# Missing hadoop installation for Windows 10

Tags: hadoop, hive, windows-10

I successfully installed Hadoop 2.8.1 on Windows 10.  Now I'm trying to install Hive version 2.1.  When I try to start hive I receive the following error:

> "Missing hadoop installation: C:\hadoop-2.8.1\bin must be set"**

[image]

I have `HADOOP_HOME` set to `D:\Hadoop-2.8.1\bin` in the environment variables and added to the path system variable. Do I have to specify this path in a hive file?

Comment: Please add your `hive-env.bat`

Comment: What about setting `HADOOP_HOME` to `D:\Hadoop-2.8.1` -- and optionally updating `PATH` with `D:\Hadoop-2.8.1\bin` at the end? _(Windows has no equivalent to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, the dynamic libs are searched in the generic `PATH`)_

Comment: @cricket_007 I have a hive-env.sh.template.  Do I need to rename this to hive-env.sh and edit this file?  I see there is a commented HADOOP_HOME variable:

***HADOOP_HOME=${bin}/../../hadoop***

Comment: Windows isn't running a `sh` file. It would be a `.bat`, but I've not ran Hive on Windows before, so I could be wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have wrongly set `HADOOP_HOME`.

In User variables, configure `HADOOP_HOME` with following value.

```
HADOOP_HOME-->D:\Hadoop-2.8.1
```

In System variables, add following value in addition of existing path value.

```
path--><Existing path values>;D:\Hadoop-2.8.1\bin;
```

If you're not ok with that above configurations just try below way.

Open cmd prompt, Just set home by setting path and home.

```
C:>set HADOOP_HOME=D:\Hadoop-2.8.1

C:>set PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
```

Now start hadoop services from same cmd prompt and then go to hive shell.

Comment: Thank you for this @Mahendra_prabhu.  I was able to get a little further after correctly setting the environment variables.  However, when I try to connect to hive I receive the following:

**Error applying authorization policy on hive configuration: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
Connection is already closed.**

Do you happen to know why I'm receiving this error?

Comment: Thanks again, @Mahendra_prabhu!  I was missing a couple .jar files for the derby database, and I needed to start the hive metastore.